# Can I render a website in iframe and get a callback if user +1'ed the page?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to embed a website inside an iframe on my page and get the callback if users +1 the website(the one in iframe).

Is this possible? I tried to google with no interesting results and maybe someone knows that beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security restrictions, you won't be able to get cross-domain contents from an <iframe>.
See [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

you can use postMessage for talking between iframes of different domains.